# How do I autofill a form based on the employee ID entered in access?

Tags: sql, database, forms, ms-access, autofill

This is my first database project so please bear with me.

I'm currently trying to design a database where I have to create a form that has to be filled out by different employees when needed. The form can be filled out by the same employee more than once. I currently have

**Table 1**-
This table has all the details that are entered in the form that directly populate the table.

**Table 2**-
This table has all the employees' names, email and employee ID.

In my form, I have used a code to automatically fill the employee ID via windows username (The forms are only filled out by company employee and their windows login name is their employee ID). I want to automatically fill out their name and email by checking the detected employee ID with the corresponding data in Table 2.

I have already tried using combo boxes (or maybe I'm not using them right) but I do not want a drop down list. I want the detected employee ID to be checked with the corresponding data in Table 2 (which already has employee ID, Name and email)

Is this possible to do without involving a drop down list?

Thank you.

Comment: In a normalized database, you would store just the employee ID in Table1 as a foreign key. you can lookup the name or email or whatever by joining the tables on employee ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Recordset like that

```vb
Sub FindEmployee
    Dim RST As DAO.Recordset, EmployeeID As Long
    ' You said you have code to get ID:
    EmployeeID = YourIDFunction()
    ' Create recordset with query to your Table2
    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Name], [Email] " _
        & " FROM Table2 WHERE EmployeeID = " & EmployeeID, dbOpenSnapshot)
    If RST.RecordCount > 0 Then
        ' Fill fields on your form with data from recordset:
        Me.NameField = RST(0)
        Me.EmailField = RST(1)
    Else
        ' Nothing is found
    End If
    ' Close and destroy recordset:
    RST.Close
    Set RST = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! I might have more questions but as long as there are people like you, I should be fine. The syntax is a little confusing to me mostly.